Attempting to sort jqGrid locally still calls server side sorting functionality
I have a jqGrid that is filled with data from the server similar to below:
$("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
        url: 'url/load.json',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        ...

One of the columns in this grid gets created and added after pulling the initial data from the server.  I was attempting to sort this column but since it is not present in the database, the default sorting for jqGrid fails causing a SQL error.  It attempts to reload the grid from the server sorting by the column that doesn't exist.
To get around this I am trying to sort locally when that specific column is clicked.
However no matter what I try the initial URL 'load.json' is still being called causing the SQL error mentioned above. Perhaps I am not doing something correctly?
In the loadComplete() function I have the following:
$("#dataGrid_ColumnToSortLocally").on('click', function()
{
    var grid = $("#dataGrid");
    var postData = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData');
    var sortName = postData.sidx;
    var sortOrder = postData.sord || 'asc';
    if (sortName === 'ColumnToSortLocally') 
    {
        var gridData = grid.jqGrid('getRowData');
        gridData.sort(function(a, b) 
        {
            return sortOrder === 'asc' ? a.ColumnToSortLocally - b.ColumnToSortLocally: b.ColumnToSortLocally - a.ColumnToSortLocally;
        });

        try
        {
            grid[0].p.datatype = 'local';
            grid[0].p.url = null;
            grid[0].p.data = gridData;
            grid[0].p.records = gridData.length;
            grid[0].p.page = 1;
            $('#dataGrid').jqGrid('clearGridData').jqGrid('setGridParam',{data: gridData}).trigger("reloadGrid");
         }
         catch (error)
         {
             console.error('An error occurred:', error);
         }
         
         grid.jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype:'json'});
     }
});

Everything seems to work fine up until I trigger a reload on the grid.  My data is present and it gets sorted correctly but when I attempt to reload the grid locally with my sorted data it still calls back to the server to sort by the column that does not exist.
How can I sort by this one specific column locally while still retaining the server sorting for the other columns?
I can include any other relevant code snippets if necessary.
I appreciate your help!

Can you please indicate which version of jqGrid (Guriddo) or free-jqGrid is used?

This solution works for me (tested)
$("#dataGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'url/load.json',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    ...
    onSortCol : function(name, index, order) {
        if(name === "ColumnToSortLocally") {
            this.p.datatype = 'local';
            this.p.data = $(this).jqGrid('getRowData');
        }
        return true;
    },
    loadComplete : function() {
        this.p.datatype = "json"
    }               
});

